# How to post multiple field in SQL server from react native

Tags: javascript, react-native, sails.js

I wasn't really sure how to describe my need in the title but I'll try to explain - 
I currently have a react native app that updates a user data that I hold in my sql server. I have one function for each type of update I want to do to a user ie:

```
export const updateUserData = (uid,username,photoUrl,fbProfile,email) => async dispatch => {
  fetch(`${API_URL}api/updateUser`, {
    method: 'POST',
    body: JSON.stringify({
      uid: uid,
      username: username,
      profilePic: photoUrl,
      fbProfile: fbProfile,
      email: email
    }),
  });
}
```

This way I know I only update certain fields in the user and don't leave parameters null which will reset any value that is already stored.

In another case when I want to update other fields, I created a dedicated function just to update those fields:

```
export const updateCityAndCountry = (uid, city, country) => async dispatch => {
  fetch(`${API_URL}api/updateUser`, {
    method: 'POST',
    body: JSON.stringify({
      uid: uid,
      city: city,
      country: country
    }),
  });
```

With this function, I know that I have `uid, country and city` to update and that all values that I pass to this function will not be null.
I know this method doesn't make sense and I want to find a solution that combines all the different function to one `updateUser` POST function.

Comment: Instead of passing the parameters directly to body, create a dynamic object with only the ones that are not null, then post them. On your back end, wait for all possible values but do the necessary conditionals when building the query.

Comment: Put only the updated info in the JSON you're sending, then build the `VALUES` part of the query by iterating over the keys.

Comment: Like this: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/1m8cws35/